# Transaction didnt rollback but committed using Hibernate JPA 2.0 and EJB3 with BMT

Tags: hibernate, transactions, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

I have been studying about JPA 2 with hibernate on ejb3.
 So I made a sample class to test the functionalities. I have tried using BMT transactions but facing problem on transaction. 
From the sample code below, if something goes wrong in `dosomething()`, an exception will be thrown and so UserTransaction will be rollbacked.
 However, I find that the edited entity is updated to the DB even the exception is thrown. Can anyone point me out if I am missing something in the setting?

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "MyManagementBean")
    @Local
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)


    public class MyManagement implements MyManagementLocal,MyManagementRemote {

        @PersistenceUnit(unitName="MyEjb") EntityManagerFactory emf;
        @Resource UserTransaction utx;
        @Resource SessionContext ctx;

        /**
         * Default constructor. 
         */
        public MyManagement () {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void dosomething(String id) throws Exception
        {

            try {
                utx.begin();    
                em = emf.createEntityManager();

                Myline line = em.find(Myline.class, id);

                line.setStatus("R");

                em.flush();
                utx.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (utx != null) utx.rollback();
                throw e; // or display error message
            }
            finally {
                em.close();
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the exception ?. Does program ever hit the call to

```
utx.rollback();
```

try

```
e.printStackTrace();
if (utx != null) {
    utx.rollback();
    system.error.println("Rolled Back");
}                
throw e; // or display error message
```

Comment: There's no exception. The whole piece of code seems to run well. Except before doing the JPA query, it auto flush and commit the previous changes to DB.

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood the question, "However, I find that the edited entity is updated to the DB even the exception is thrown. Can anyone point me out if I am missing something in the setting?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516973/hibernate-entity-manager-auto-flush-before-query-and-commit-changes-to-db-in-tran/6537016#6537016 - related question with more detail